# Create Pandas columns by multiplying one column by an array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in a Pandas DataFrame containing float values that I need to multiply by an array of 50 random numbers, generated differently for each row, which needs to be stored as 50 new columns in the DataFrame. What is the best way to do this?

This is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colnum = 50
b = ["t"+str(x) for x in np.arange(colnum)] # new column names
df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['num']) # exemplificative DataFrame
df[b] = df[["num"]].apply(lambda x: [x * j for j in np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum)], axis=1)
```

I'm close but the result of apply is a list of lists and doesn't fit in the new columns.

Comment: so you want to multiply each value by a different random number? Not the same per column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` method along with the `pd.Series` constructor to create new columns with the random values multiplied by the original column's values. Here's how you can do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colnum = 50
b = ["t" + str(x) for x in range(colnum)]  # new column names
df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['num'])  # exemplificative DataFrame

# Generate random values for each row and multiply them by the 'num' column
df[b] = df['num'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum) * x))

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

The warning you're seeing is due to the use of pd.Series within the apply function. Starting from pandas version 1.0.0, returning a DataFrame from Series.apply is deprecated, and you're encouraged to use DataFrame.apply instead.

To fix this issue, you can create a DataFrame from the random values and then concatenate it with the original DataFrame. Here's the sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colnum = 50
b = ["t" + str(x) for x in range(colnum)]  # new column names
df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['num'])  # exemplificative DataFrame

# Generate random values for each row and create a DataFrame
random_values = pd.DataFrame(np.random.lognormal(0, 1, size=(df.shape[0], colnum)), columns=b)

# Multiply the random values by the 'num' column
df = pd.concat([df, random_values.mul(df['num'], axis=0)], axis=1)

# Print the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

You can check on my kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/edgarsitohang/notebook8551cb8eb6)

Comment: Thank you, this is the clearer solution for me but I get _FutureWarning: Returning a DataFrame from Series.apply when the supplied function returns a Series is deprecated and will be removed in a future version._. Moreover the kaggle link gives 404

Comment: kaggle link updated. Forget to set public

Comment: This would be the perfect solution, is there a way to solve the FutureWarning?

Comment: Added code with dataframe instead of series apply

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) or numpy broadcasting for multiple with `DataFrame` constructor and add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
colnum = 5
b = ["t"+str(x) for x in np.arange(colnum)] # new column names
df = pd.DataFrame([[i] for i in range(10)], columns=['num'])
```

---

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.outer(df['num'], np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum)), 
                           index=df.index, columns=b))
```

Or:

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['num'].to_numpy()[:, None] * 
                           np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum), 
                           index=df.index, columns=b))
print (out)
   num        t0         t1        t2        t3        t4
0    0  0.000000   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
1    1  0.408033   1.130455  0.173061  0.609198  1.036017
2    2  0.816067   2.260910  0.346122  1.218396  2.072033
3    3  1.224100   3.391365  0.519183  1.827594  3.108050
4    4  1.632133   4.521819  0.692244  2.436792  4.144066
5    5  2.040166   5.652274  0.865305  3.045990  5.180083
6    6  2.448200   6.782729  1.038367  3.655188  6.216099
7    7  2.856233   7.913184  1.211428  4.264386  7.252116
8    8  3.264266   9.043639  1.384489  4.873584  8.288132
9    9  3.672299  10.174094  1.557550  5.482782  9.324149
```

If really need loop by rows, what is slow and not recommended:

```
df[b] = pd.DataFrame(df['num'].apply(lambda x: np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum) * x).to_numpy().tolist(),
                  columns=b)
```

---

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['num'].apply(lambda x: np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum) * x).to_numpy().tolist(),
                  columns=b))
```

Comment: This solution works fine but the lognormal is only run once, instead I need it to be re-run for each row in df

Comment: @AlexZabeo - Sure, it is recommned for performance. Why need loop by each row?

Comment: @AlexZabeo - EDITed answer for loop solution.

Comment: it's not I need loops per se but I need the lognormal draws to be different for each row. Thank you for the update.

Answer (score 0):

##### using the same random number per colum

You can use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting to expand the dimensions and modify the DataFrame in place:

```
df[b] = df['num'].to_numpy()[:, None] * np.random.lognormal(0, 1, len(b))
```

If you want a copy, convert the array with the [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor, and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the output to the original DataFrame:

```
out = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df['num'].to_numpy()[:, None]
                          *np.random.lognormal(0, 1, len(b)),
                           index=df.index, columns=b)
              )
```

Output:

```
   num        t0         t1         t2        t3  ...       t49
0    0  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000
1    1  0.238805   1.452507   1.834190  0.587846  ...  0.568393
2    2  0.477611   2.905014   3.668380  1.175691  ...  1.136786
3    3  0.716416   4.357521   5.502570  1.763537  ...  1.705179
4    4  0.955222   5.810028   7.336759  2.351383  ...  2.273572
5    5  1.194027   7.262535   9.170949  2.939229  ...  2.841965
6    6  1.432833   8.715042  11.005139  3.527074  ...  3.410358
7    7  1.671638  10.167549  12.839329  4.114920  ...  3.978751
8    8  1.910444  11.620056  14.673519  4.702766  ...  4.547145
9    9  2.149249  13.072563  16.507709  5.290612  ...  5.115538
```

##### using a different random number for each row/column

Here you need to generate a full `len(df)*len(b)` array:

```
df[b] = (df['num'].to_numpy()[:, None]
        * np.random.lognormal(0, 1, size=(len(df), len(b)))
        )
```

Output:

```
   num         t0         t1          t2         t3         t4  ...        t49
0    0   0.000000   0.000000    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000  ...   0.000000
1    1   3.374763   0.155016    2.983870   1.118683   0.148411  ...   0.169681
2    2   1.836595   1.182172    4.116855   0.500947   1.273747  ...   1.151483
3    3   3.252562   3.242497    3.984252   4.245168   2.470467  ...  16.970237
4    4  10.312770  15.572542    1.140875   2.223080   1.431785  ...  13.080211
5    5   4.588487   1.166549   10.223821  21.357885  17.686545  ...   6.439549
6    6  14.374197   5.255399    0.831558   5.311416   5.968454  ...   2.433229
7    7  15.842484  15.674480    4.357442  22.725804  18.848937  ...   5.650013
8    8   5.748938   6.973152  106.500776   5.160046   0.486047  ...   1.158642
9    9   1.949575   4.528149   24.329826   7.972248   1.056742  ...  14.795512
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use apply with pd.Series in this case.

```
df[b] = df["num"].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.random.lognormal(0, 1, colnum)))
```

This code will create 50 new columns from `t0` to `t49` in your DataFrame, and each column will contain a different random number generated for each row based on the lognormal distribution.